# ios NSIndexPath insertItemsAtIndexPaths in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, insert, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I'm using insertItemsAtIndexPaths but I'm trying to understand how this function affects ordering of my index paths.

I have 1 section and multiple items (or rows). I'm using a UICollectionView.

When I insert new items, I use insertItemsAtIndexPaths with [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]. My question is, do the index paths that already in this collectionview shift when I insert at indexPathForItem 0? In other words, say I looped indexPathForItem:0. Would that essentially push items at the beginning of the UICollectionView?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UICollectionView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UICollectionView), you first update your data source, and then you call the insert method.  So if your data source is an array of 3 elements (e.g. A, B, C), and you add a new element D at position 0 you now have @[D, A, B, C].  You would then call [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSInexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]];.

If the layout indicates that this affects any items on screen then the cellForItemAtIndexPath method will be called the affected rows and the data source will return what to show in them.